# When is it ok to increase the max stack size of the jvm (-Xss)?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

**What am I doing ?**

I am doing a course on coursera which requires me to write a program that calculates the height of a tree. The input is a parent array where each index is the node and its value is the node's parent. If the node is the root its value will be -1.

**What have I done so far ?**

I wrote an algorithm that checks the height of the tree by recursively traversing its children upto its root node and saving the intermediate children's height in an array (depth variable). Since it's a `recursion` I often see a `stackoverflow exception` which is natural since the stack size won't suffice for big trees.

In order to get rid of this exception I tried finding the best value for my recursive calls and it came out to be somewhere near **3100k**. Also, when I saw the code that is testing my algorithm against some predefined testcases also has passed in a **stack size of 1 << 26** into the thread constructor.

**What do I need to know ?**

1. Is there a better way to solve this problem ?
2. Is it okay to increase the stack size like this ?

**Here is the code**

```
int computeHeight() {
    int[] depth = new int[n];
    int maxHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int height = computeHeight(parent, depth, i);
        maxHeight = Math.max(height, maxHeight);
    }
    return maxHeight;
}

private int computeHeight(int[] parent, int[] depth, int idx) {
    if (parent[idx] == -1) {
        // root found
        depth[idx] = 1;
        return depth[idx];
    }
    // depth of parent unknown
    if (depth[parent[idx]] == 0) {
        computeHeight(parent, depth, parent[idx]);
    }
    depth[idx] = depth[parent[idx]] + 1;
    return depth[idx];
}
```

Comment: the link gives 404

Comment: IT looks quite strange that you need more than 3.1M stack frames. If you implemented this correctly, this should only happen for trees with a depth that is more than 3.1M.

Comment: If you can do it recursively, I am sure there is an iterative way. Increasing the stack size isn't always recommended approach unless and until absolutely necessary.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
AN off-site link is not acceptable.

Comment: I am so sorry about the link. I forgot to change the repo to public. Ill do it.

Comment: @Prune Can you please unflag the question as off topic. I did add the code earlier but github repository wasn't accessible then. I have pasted the block of code that will work if you just copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that you are encountering a stack overflow error with what I'm assuming is such a simple problem; this only tends to be an issue with recursion when it is a very large tree or you are loading large amounts of RAM during it for some reason. I would suggest you post your code.

As for increasing the stack size, this is not a problem since you are just doing a practice problem. In the real world however, this could present a challenge and is one of the risks of using recursion. If you are using your application on a wide range of devices, increasing the stack size might not always be practical due to limitations depending on the device. Instead, I would suggest you avoid using recursion when possible, unless you know that the tree you are recursing is small enough to not cause an overflow.

For an alternative solution, try [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/08/inorder-traversal-of-binary-tree-in-java-recursion-iteration-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the tree is lopsided to right or left for e.g. if every node has only a right child, then recursion could easily lead to stackoverflow ( again depends on stack settings ), not sure if one of the inputs has that in your case.

This could be done in an iterative fashion:

a) Add all parents ( values in the array ) to a HashSet

b) Then go through all nodes ( here just indices from 0 to n ) and see if it is present in the set, if not it is a leaf.

c) then traverse from leaf upto root to get the height, while doing so store the height at each node in an array so next time you won't have to climb up the same path again.

d) Update maximum height each time.

Comment: Please take a look at the code if you can. The link is working now

Answer (score 0):

In real life work, you should only use recursion when you *know* that the depth is limited to a small value.

Recursively measuring a *balanced* tree is fine, for example, but recursively measuring an unbalanced tree is not.

Comment: Please take a look at the code link now. Its working now.